# How do I set Stereo Music,Setting Sub woofer

Tags: sound

I have freshly installed Ubuntu in hp-envy dv-7 with beats audio.
I noticed the audio playback is poor and the sub woofer wasn't activated all through.
How do I set the audio to stereo mode and activate the sub woofers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I have found so far is to retask the audio using “HDAJackRetask” which is part of the “alsa-tools-gui” package.
Install the package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Once installed head over to the Dash and start typing HDA until you see the Icon for HDAJackRetask appear then run the application.

Follow the following steps.

1. At the top, in codec section, select IDT 92HD91BXX codec. You just have to play on three pins. They are 0x0d , 0x0f and 0×10.
2. Go to the section having pin id : 0x0d . Change (Internal Speaker, Front side) to “Internal speaker”.
3. Go to the section having pin id: 0x0f. Change (Not connected) to “Internal speaker”. This part is about the under-display speakers.
4. Go to the section having pin id: 0×10. Change (Not connected) to “Internal speaker (LFE)”. This part is about the subwoofer.
5. You are finally done with those pin settings. Apply it now. You can test with some sound. Check whether all the speakers are producing the desired sound.
6. If everything is alright, install boot override from the bottom right side and restart your device.

Finally you must have sound with Beats Audio. Enjoy the sound and music. Also plug in the headphones, it must disable the external sound when the headphone is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings-->sound-->under the output tab click on the simultaneous output to built in Audio Analog Stereo